# Harvard Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I'm currently using the harvard package for the bibliography but I need to add the cite in the bibliography.

### Code

```
\usepackage{harvard}
\harvardparenthesis{square}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Want

How can I obtain the `[Mon05]` part like this:

[image: Want]

Comment: Don't use `harvard`, but `natbib` with `abbrvnat` as bibstyle.

Comment: @egreg Using natbib gives me some problem with `\citeasnoun{}`

Comment: Do you want to switch from harvard style to a 'alpha-numerical' style globally or only in the references list? What you want is provided by \bibliographystyle{alpha} (will switch globally).

Comment: With `natbib` use `\citet` for that.

Comment: @egreg I tried with your setup but [THIS](http://cl.ly/image/0H152N1l1S1X/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-01%20at%2012.24.34.png) is what i get.

Comment: @remus Using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` how can I keep the long cite insted of the short: [Example](http://cl.ly/image/1q0C1w3V1Z3F/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-01%20at%2012.30.42.png)

Comment: @gmeroni Yes, I thought it did differently. But using those `[Mon05]` keys doesn't make sense with an author-year citation style.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you actually don't want a "Harvard bibliography" but an alphabetic style. You also talk about a "long cite". Here is how I would do alphabetic citations (with Biblatex), and I include a `\textcite` in the example, which maybe is what you were lacking.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{book1,
  author =       {U. K. Nown},
  year =         2012,
  title =   {Book1}}

@Book{book2,
  author =       {A. U. Thor},
  year =         2013,
  title =   {Book2}}

@Book{book3,
  author =       {A. U. Thor},
  year =         2014,
  title =   {Book3}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bla bla \cite{book1}.
Bla bla \cite{book2}.
Bla bla \cite{book3}.

But \textcite{book2} shows that \( 2+2=4 \).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want this; with an author-year citation style labels such as “[Mon05]” are useless.

However, here's a way to get them with `natbib`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{montgomery2005,
 author={Montgomery, D. C.},
 title={Progettazione e analisi degli esperimenti},
 publisher={McGraw-Hill},
 address={Milano},
 year={2005},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}}
  {\my@NAT@anchor{#1}{#2}}
  {}{}
\def\my@NAT@anchor#1#2{%
  \hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}%
  \expandafter\@biblabel\expandafter{\@makeabbrev#1}%
  \hyper@natanchorend
}
\def\@makeabbrev#1#2#3#4(#5#6#7){#1#2#3#7}
\let\NATORIG@thebibliography\thebibliography
\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \let\@biblabel\NAT@biblabelnum
  \NATORIG@thebibliography{}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\@bibsetup#1{%
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{MMM00}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-2\bibsep}%
    \setlength {\parsep}{\z@}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Citazione in parentesi: \citep{montgomery2005}.

Citazione in testo: \citet{montgomery2005}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]